# Realm-js in React Native not working in M1 chip

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, react-native-ios, apple-m1

Goals

What are you trying to achieve?

Installing Realm-js in React native project

Steps to Reproduce

What are steps we can follow to reproduce this issue?

Only In M1 Chip Not Working Realm

1. React-native init test
2. npm install realm
3. cd ios && pod install
4. cd .. && react-native run-ios

Version of Realm and Tooling

Realm JS SDK Version: 10.2.0

Node or React Native: v14.15.3 Or RN:- 0.63.4

Client OS & Version: big sur & version 11.2.1 (20D74) (M1 CHIP)

Answer (score 0):

I downgrade the version to 6.1.6 it worked.